# Check if display is at sleep or receive sleep notifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have an application utility which becomes useless when there's no user. So, in order to save resources, I'd like it to know when/whether display is at sleep.

There's a [dedicated article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2004/qa1340.html) about wake/sleep notifications by apple, but it deals only with computer sleep and not display sleep.

Is there a way for application to 'hibernate' when display is at sleep?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn´t find any call issued by the display falling to sleep (maybe the screensaver does that? It´s very likely to kick in before the system falls to sleep), I´d suggest detecting the idle time manually and then comparing it to the display sleep settings. 
[This article](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/articles/iokit-idle/) covers how to get the idle time from IOKit and you should be able to easily get the current sleep settings, e.g. with  "pmset -g | grep sleep".

Two minutes after posting the above, I discovered an open source command line tool that will probably help you a lot getting there: [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) seems to be able to do just what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out! SleepWatcher seems to be simple enough to be included in the application directly.

Answer (score 9):

The DisplayWrangler service sends notifications for when the display will power off:

```
// Doesn't include error checking - just a quick example
io_service_t displayWrangler;
IONotificationPortRef notificationPort;
io_object_t notification;

displayWrangler = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceNameMatching("IODisplayWrangler");
notificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(kIOMasterPortDefault);
IOServiceAddInterestNotification(notificationPort, displayWrangler, kIOGeneralInterest, displayPowerNotificationsCallback, NULL, &notification);

CFRunLoopAddSource (CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notificationPort), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
IOObjectRelease (displayWrangler);
```

Then the callback looks something like this:

```
void displayPowerNotificationsCallback(void *refcon, io_service_t service, natural_t messageType, void *messageArgument)
{
   switch (messageType) {
   case kIOMessageDeviceWillPowerOff :
      // This is called twice - once for display dim event, then once 
      // for display power off
      break;
   case kIOMessageDeviceHasPoweredOn :
      // Display powering back on
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is response to a question asked a while ago - but I thought it would be useful to add my answer.

[NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a couple of notifications for when displays wake and sleep: NSWorkspaceScreensDidSleepNotification and NSWorkspaceScreensDidWakeNotification